# Ionic cordova-video-player

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Estou tentando adicionar vídeo no aplicativo seguindo este tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4S1yVBUPpk&t=9s

Fiz tudo certo eu acredito, mas quando executo o aplicativo com ionic serve -c ,  e abro no Ionic DevApp  recebo a mensagem ao clicar no botão de PlayVideo:

> console.warn: Native: tried calling VideoPlayer.play, but the VideoPlayer plugin is not installed.
>
> [15:49:16]  console.warn: Install the VideoPlayer plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git'.

Mas eu tenho o plugin instalado, ja removi e instalei, cheguei a criar outros projetos mas sempre no final retorna esse erro como se nao tivesse o plugin instalado. Ele ainda aparece em "plugins". Alguém sabe o que pode ser isso?  Pode ser do Ionic DevApp? Não tenho emulador para testar, apenas o devapp.
E não achei muitos tutoriais sobre como por vídeo no aplicativo. Eu na verdade irei adicionar uma imagem, e clicando nela reproduzir o vídeo, uma verdadeira "propaganda". Mas a princípio estou tentando adicionar o vídeo.   Se alguem conseguir me ajudar, serei muito grato. Obrigado!

Meu código Home.Ts é :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VideoPlayer, VideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/video-player';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  videoOptions: VideoOptions;
  videoUrl: string;

  constructor(private videoPlayer: VideoPlayer, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  async playVideo() {
    try {
      this.videoOptions = {
        volume: 0.7
      }
      this.videoUrl = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
      this.videoPlayer.play(this.videoUrl, this.videoOptions)
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rodou o `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-video-player` e o `npm install @ionic-native/video-player --save` e reiniciou o `serve` após isso? Rodou os comandos na pasta do projeto?

Comment: Quando você diz reiniciou o serve, oq significa? mas eu rodei o ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-video-player (videoplayer  sem "  -  " ) e o npm install @ionic-native/video-player --save  dentro do projeto, ambos foram instalados.

Comment: Você esta desenvolvendo via comando `ionic serve` ou direto no emulador/celular? Se for no emulador/celular então ignora a parte de reiniciar.

Comment: Estou usando ionic serve, mas no chrome quando clico em Play Video, da a mensagem que o cordova nao esta disponivel no navegador. Porém eu abri pelo aplicativo ionic devapp. e nele quando clico em play video, recebo a mensagem q o plugin n foi instalado

Comment: Ah sim é verdade, plugins do cordova só rodam pelo emulador, então faz o seguinte roda o comando `ionic doctor list`, isso ai vai listar problemas possiveis.

Comment: digitei e recebi isso: 
automatic-updates-off -------
npm-installed-locally -------
ionic-installed-locally -------
git-not-used -----
git-config-invalid -------
ionic-angular-update-available ------
ionic-angular-major-update-available ------
app-scripts-update-available -----
app-scripts-major-update-available -----
ionic-native-old-version-installed -------
ionic-native-update-available ------
ionic-native-major-update-available -------
unsaved-cordova-platforms -----
cordova-platforms-committed ----
default-cordova-bundle-id-used ------
viewport-fit-not-set. ----

Comment: Nossa, tá cheio de problemas :/

Comment: Faz um backup do teu projeto em um ZIP ou RAR, então depois executa o comando `ionic doctor check`

Comment: Tudo isso então sao problemas?  Eu ainda estou aprendendo sobre isso..  Mas tudo que consta quando uso o "ionic doctor list" são problemas? gostaria de saber.   Vou usar o comando ionic doctor check

Comment: Sim e não, tem coisas desatualizadas, coisas antigas que ainda funcionam mas podem ser substituidas, e coisas que já deveriam ter sido removidas/atualizadas. Claro que não vale a pena atualizar sempre, tem antigo que funciona bem, as vezes funciona melhor que novos por causa de outras dependencias (não que seja melhor de fato)

Comment: Obrigado por me responder @GuilhermeNascimento. recebi isso apos o comando:

Comment: Play Store, the bundle ID can't be changed. This issue was detected because this app's bundle ID is
       "io.ionic.starter", which is the default bundle ID provided after running ionic start. To fix, take the following
       step(s):

            1) Change the id attribute of <widget> (root element) to something other than "io.ionic.starter"

       Ignore this issue with: ionic doctor ignore default-cordova-bundle-id-used

Comment: Vixe, tá cheio de problema :/ inclusive de configuração do teu APP. Tem como criar um projeto do zero separado?

Comment: Claro. eu vou tentar novamente quando chegar em casa em outro computador. talvez o resultado seja diferente,  mas eu posto aqui o resultado. e mais uma vez muito obrigado por me responder.

Comment: Acho que teu NPM e teus plugins globais possam estar desatualizados em geral :/, pode ser vários problemas, tive o mesmo problema (não o mesmo exatamente), ai removi tudo e instalei novamente, só fiz backup dos projetos, mas removi a pasta dos projetos que continham os pacotes e revisei o package.json. Claro que no meu caso tive que remover até o packages.json e começar um projeto do zero, só copiando a pasta src e app (e assets), agora aqui tá rodando legal